# Omnet - How to run parameter case study

Tags: simulation, omnet++

Im simulating some network, in which I have some param which is exponentially distributed, set in the ini file, with simulation time also defined:

```
next_transmission = exponential(1/${0.1..0.9 step 0.1})
sim-time-limit = 500s
```

I basically want the simulation to run 9 different times, each time for 500 sec,  with the given param getting different value at every time.

The result currently is that when running the simulation, I get the option of what param value between the 9 possibilities to use, making me need to manually run the simulation  9 times,choosing different value each time

Is there a way to 'automate' it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, if you want to run a simulation batch you should either start the batch from the IDE and configure it in the launch dialog to run in `Cmdenv` or run from the command line using the `opprun_all` command. Generally, you should read the manual's corresponding chapter which describes exactly how to run simulation batches.